# Extracting CID from Reference or ID

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible to extract the CID of a business from the Reference or the ID of the business?  I'd rather not have to re-write all of my scripts to get the canonical URL of the business since I'm already getting the Reference and the ID.

I believe this question is the opposite of a question previously asked.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do so. An indirect way is to do a place details request, which will return the cid in the `url` field.

To perform a place details call, follow their doc present [at this address](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests) . It is very straightforward, albeit a bit annoying to have to perform an extra call. I don't know about you, but I have never been very fond of the Places API for that reason - too many requests for not enough data.